# Difficulty loading FXML file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Here is my class where I've written the one liner code to link the fxml file to the project I'm working on:

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;


public class towerOfHanoi extends Application implements Initializable 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception 
    {       
        try
        {
            Parent rootContainer = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/userInterface.fxml"));
        Scene s=new Scene(rootContainer);
        primaryStage.setScene(s);
        //primaryStage.setTitle("Towers Of Hanoi");
        primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {               
        //          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

@Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Any time I try to run this in eclipse, nothing happens. The square to terminate is red as if something is happening, but the UI I created in scenebuilder doesn't show.

****Update:
This is the complete stack trace when I uncomment that piece of code:

```
Mar 14, 2017 4:01:49 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.102 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.101
javafx.fxml.LoadException: No controller specified.
/F:/2nd%20Year%20College%20Stuff/Semester%202/Event-driven%20Programming/2nd%20Year%20Workspace/CA%202/bin/application/userInterface.fxml:44

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.getControllerMethodHandle(FXMLLoader.java:557)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:599)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:770)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at application.towerOfHanoi.start(towerOfHanoi.java:29)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Try uncommenting e.printStackTrace();

Comment: Additionally, note that Initializable is only called for controller classes... you don't typically use it your Application subclass...

Comment: If I comment it out I get a very huge error.

Comment: I've updated the OP with the stack trace.

Comment: I'm new to JavaFX. So I don't really understand what that means..do u mind explaining step by step please?

Comment: It means you didn't specify a controller in the FXML file.

Comment: Okay, so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @J.Doe look down at my answer, i have edited it

Comment: @azro I'll try that now, thanks.

Comment: @azro Please view the updated OP..I'm still getting errors :(

Comment: @J.Doe can you give line n°22 of the fxml please ?

Comment: Don't vandalize your post.

Comment: I rolled this back to rev 3. The currently-provided answer answers the question as it stood in that revision. This solution apparently unearthed further issues (in code that has not been posted at any point) and the OP edited the question to ask about those further issues. That should be a separate question, and that edit detracts from the posted answer. The post was subsequently vandalized after that. This rev + the answer is (imo) the most potentially useful combination for other users.

Answer (score 4):

As the error tells you : you need to ***associate*** a controller to the .fxml, like this :

**FILE userInterface.fxml** (you can have another container than a BorderPane but it will be the same, it has to be on the root parent)

```
<BorderPane fx:id="background" fx:controller="application.Controller">
  //Content ...
</BorderPane>
```

you can set the Controller into the fxml (see above) OR by SceneBuilder:

[image]

---

Also It will be clearer to separate the Launcher and the controller, like this :

**FILE towerOfHanoi.java**

```
public class towerOfHanoi extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{       
        try{
            Parent rootContainer = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/userInterface.fxml"));
            Scene s=new Scene(rootContainer);
            primaryStage.setScene(s);
            //primaryStage.setTitle("Towers Of Hanoi");
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch(IOException e){               
        //          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**FILE Controller.java**

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: Then what do you need me to add to the OP to help find the cause or the error?

Comment: OK, so it turns out that now the OP includes the stack trace, this does answer the question. :).

Comment: @James_D he update with the stack trace after my answer, I've updated so